# Displacement modifier - auto reload image texture

Tags: modifiers, image, displacement

I'm paiting my displacement texture, and I have to click any option on the modifier or change mode on the right panel to refresh the actual displacement.
Is it possible to make modifier automaticly reload the texture, so I can see displacement while I'm paitning, not forcing me to reload it by hand every time I draw something?

I don't have to change anything in the image texture. I just have to for example increase strength or toggle "edit mode" in modifier.
[image]